# Is there a way to have python read what is printed in my shell and display what is printed back from where I read it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For my school project, I am creating an application that will display what classes you have and when each day on your desktop. I have the entries where you type what you class you have called the first latter of the day, if its week 1 or 2, and then which period it is in ie "M1_1". I use the code I show here to see what you type into my entire box and print it into the shell when click the confirm button. I was wondering if there's a way to have python read that back and always display what was last typed in the shell back when you launch it since right now when you re-launch the app all your info is gone.

Here is what I have:

```
inputValue = M1_1.get()
print(inputValue)
inputValue = M1_2.get()
print(inputValue)
inputValue = M1_3.get()
print(inputValue)
inputValue = M1_4.get()
print(inputValue)
inputValue = M1_5.get()
print(inputValue)

ButtonCommit = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Confirm",
                  command=lambda: retrieve_input())
buttonCommit.pack()
```

Comment: I think your question is about having your data persist across different python "sessions" ("once you exit python, can you get your data back from last time?"). An easy way to do this is to serialize your data and store it in a file - take a look at [`pickle'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Read about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)